# appendChild issue inside loop

Tags: jquery, html, dom, appendchild

I use the following code to create a image slider with popup feature to show zoomed version. Here for 360 view images I add a overlay image.

```
$('.imageSet').each(function(){
    $(this).css({left : left+'%'});
    var mainImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
    var mainImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    mainImg.src = $(this).attr('data-big');
    mainImgWrapper.id = $(this).attr('data-img-id');
    var orbitImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    orbitImg.src = "/base/media/img/icons/rotate.png";
    orbitImg.className = 'orbitIcon';
    if($(this).hasClass('orbitView')){
        mainImgWrapper.className = 'mainImage orbitView clickable';
        mainImgWrapper.appendChild(orbitImg);
    }else{
        mainImgWrapper.className = 'mainImage clickable';
    }
    mainImgWrapper.style.left = 'calc('+(imgCount*100)+'% + '+imgCount+'px)';
    mainImgWrapper.appendChild(mainImg);
    $('#mainImages').append(mainImgWrapper);

    var popImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
    var popImg = document.createElement("IMG");
    popImg.src = $(this).attr('data-big');
    popImgWrapper.dataset.imgId = $(this).attr('data-img-id');
    if($(this).hasClass('orbitView')){
        popImgWrapper.className = 'popImage orbitView';
        popImgWrapper.appendChild(orbitImg);
    }else{
        popImgWrapper.className = 'popImage';
    }
    popImgWrapper.style.left = (imgCount*100)+'%';
    popImgWrapper.appendChild(popImg);
    $('#imagePopupView').append(popImgWrapper);
    imgCount++;
    left = left + 25.5;
});
```

When the .imageSet has class "orbitView" I append the orbitImg to the mainImgWrapper and do the same with popImgWrapper. But the orbitImg only gets appended to the popImgWrapper. I can't find any sort of issue with the code or either in execution environment. May I am missing something which I am not able to see for myself.

Comment: Could you provide me with a jsfiddle? I would like to look into it

Comment: @Lesleyvdp I was able to find the issue. Please check my answer. Thanks for you effort towards helping me out :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue here. As for the HTML standards you can not append a html node twice. If you do so it will only execute the last attempt. The reason is if accidentally you have added an ID to the html node and if HTML allows you to add that same node as a child multiple times, it will repeat the same ID multiple times. You can see it in example from following two fiddles. How it overrides the attempt to append the same node as a child and how it works when you append different nodes. So if you need to append something in a loop you need to create a fresh node every time. And in my case I even had to append the same node twice inside the loop. So I ended up creating two fresh nodes every time I go through the loop.

Same child appended twice only works for the second div

```js
var mainImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
mainImgWrapper.style.width = 100+'px';
mainImgWrapper.style.height = 100+'px';
mainImgWrapper.style.background = 'red';

var secondImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
secondImgWrapper.style.width = 100+'px';
secondImgWrapper.style.height = 100+'px';
secondImgWrapper.style.background = 'green';

var appendChild = document.createElement("IMG");
appendChild.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/457702/pexels-photo-457702.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260';
appendChild.width = 100;

mainImgWrapper.appendChild(appendChild);
secondImgWrapper.appendChild(appendChild);

document.body.appendChild(mainImgWrapper);
document.body.appendChild(secondImgWrapper);
```

Different child appended works for both divs

```js
var firstImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
firstImgWrapper.style.width = 100+'px';
firstImgWrapper.style.height = 100+'px';
firstImgWrapper.style.background = 'red';

var secondImgWrapper = document.createElement("DIV");
secondImgWrapper.style.width = 100+'px';
secondImgWrapper.style.height = 100+'px';
secondImgWrapper.style.background = 'green';

var firstChildImg = document.createElement("IMG");
firstChildImg.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/457702/pexels-photo-457702.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260';
firstChildImg.width = 100;

var secondChildImg = document.createElement("IMG");
secondChildImg.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/457702/pexels-photo-457702.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260';
secondChildImg.width = 100;

firstImgWrapper.appendChild(firstChildImg);
secondImgWrapper.appendChild(secondChildImg);

document.body.appendChild(firstImgWrapper);
document.body.appendChild(secondImgWrapper);
```